# Can you add your own fonts in your react native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and I followed a basic course on react-native but the course did not speak about adding fonts to your app and I was wondering if it was possible to do so.

Comment: I didn't need to search for an eternity to find this one: https://mehrankhandev.medium.com/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4
...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if you are using expo for your React-Native project, u should try following  steps:

1. Install  [Expo-Font Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-font)

2.Import `useFonts` hook from expo fonts `import { useFonts } from "expo-font";`

3.Import All your local fonts:

```js
//fontsLoaded returns boolean u can check this and render application conditionaliy
let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        GEO_UltLt: require("./assets/fonts/mainfont/UltLt.ttf"),
        GEO_Thin: require("./assets/fonts/mainfont/Thin.ttf"),
        GEO_Light: require("./assets/fonts/mainfont/Light.ttf"),
        GEO_Medium: require("./assets/fonts/mainfont/Medium.ttf"),
        GEO_Bold: require("./assets/fonts/mainfont/Bold.ttf"),
        GEO_Heavy: require("./assets/fonts/mainfont/Heavy.ttf"),
        GEO_Black: require("./assets/fonts/mainfont/Black.ttf"),
    });
```

4.And use inside app like this

```js
 //inside app
 input: {
        flex: 1,
        color: "#323f4b",
        fontFamily:"GEO_Medium"
  }
```

Comment: @MegaMindTheCoder Pls, accept current answer  if solution is correct

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer theUltimateKafka it was very helpful. I replied 2 days ago but when I got out of the website it deleted my comment